# convert Decimal array to Double array

Tags: c#, arrays, double, decimal

What's an efficient and hopefully elegant incantation to convert `decimal[]` to `double[]`?
I'm working with some fairly large arrays.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
double[] doubleArray = Array.ConvertAll(decimalArray, x => (double)x);
```

Comment: Would this be faster than `decimalArray.Select(d => (double)d).ToArray()`?

Comment: @Tobias I was also interested, so I created some small tests and the answer to your question is **yes** but how much faster, it depends on those two types and also if you are in Debug or Release - for 20,000,000 `decimal`s `ConvertAll` lasts in average 628ms in Debug and 245ms in Release and your method lasts 1015ms in Debug and 573ms in Release in average on my computer. `ConvertAll` also consumes less memory - it handled approx. 80,000,000 `float`s to `double`s and your method *only* around 30,000,000 before `System.OutOfMemoryException` was thrown with the same settings. Tested on .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3):

You also can use and extension classes similar to this one

```
public static class ArrayExtension
{

   public static double[] ToDouble(this float[] arr) => 
                                    Array.ConvertAll(arr, x => (double)x);

}
```

Then:

```
double[] doubleArr = decimalArr.ToDouble();
```