# How does C# convert double arrays to float arrays or int arrays?

Tags: c#

I have multiple `double` values that need to be converted into a `float array` or `int array`, what should I do?

E.g.

```
double[] values= new double[]{123.456,234.123};
float[] floatValues=xxxx(values);
```

Comment: `var floatValues = values.Cast<float>()` ? What are the results here. You can just say i want to smash a big object into a little object and not care whats missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Cast Entire Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068120/c-sharp-cast-entire-array) or [convert Decimal array to Double array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4175716/150605)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do it element-wise. There are multiple ways to achieve that.

1. You could foreach over the source array like

   ```
    floatvalues = new float[values.Length];
    for(var i = 0;i < values.Length;++i)
        floatValues[i] = (float)values[i];
   ```
2. You could use LINQ for simplifying the loop

   ```
    floatValues = values.Select(d => (float)d).ToArray();
   ```
3. You can use `Cast<T>()`

   ```
    floatValues = values.Cast<float>().ToArray();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with Linq:

```
using Sytem.Linq;

double[] values= new double[]{123.456,234.123};
float[] floatValues= values.Cast<float>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'.

Answer (score 1):

Alternet way is to use [`Array.ConvertAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-5.0),

> Converts an array of one type to an array of another type.

```
float[] floatValues = Array.ConvertAll(values, float.Parse);
```

Comment: The converter should be `Convert.ToSingle` instead of `float.Parse`.